# How to call javascript function after click of a button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, button

Hi i'm having problem in calling the below javascript after click of a button. 
I also need a code to insert button with which I can call the below JS function. The only requirement is that the result of the script should not display in the page before click of a button. Further, the button will stay at its position unchanged even after the execution of the script. The page shouldn't reload after clicking on the button. The resultant feed should run below the button only as a section in the page.

```
    <!-- start feedwind code --><script type="text/javascript">document.write('\x3Cscript type="text/javascript" src="' + ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://' : 'http://') + 'feed.mikle.com/js/rssmikle.js">\x3C/script>');</script><script type="text/javascript">(function() {var params = {rssmikle_url: "http://news.google.co.in/news?pz=1&cf=all&ned=in&hl=en&topic=n&output=rss",rssmikle_frame_width: "400",rssmikle_frame_height: "500",frame_height_by_article: "0",rssmikle_target: "_blank",rssmikle_font: "Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif",rssmikle_font_size: "12",rssmikle_border: "off",responsive: "off",rssmikle_css_url: "",text_align: "left",text_align2: "left",corner: "off",scrollbar: "on",autoscroll: "on_mc",scrolldirection: "up",scrollstep: "3",mcspeed: "30",sort: "New",rssmikle_title: "on",rssmikle_title_sentence: "Indian Latest News - As it happens",rssmikle_title_link: "",rssmikle_title_bgcolor: "#0066FF",rssmikle_title_color: "#FFFFFF",rssmikle_title_bgimage: "",rssmikle_item_bgcolor: "#FFFFFF",rssmikle_item_bgimage: "",rssmikle_item_title_length: "55",rssmikle_item_title_color: "#0066FF",rssmikle_item_border_bottom: "on",rssmikle_item_description: "on",item_link: "on",rssmikle_item_description_length: "150",rssmikle_item_description_color: "#666666",rssmikle_item_date: "gl1",rssmikle_timezone: "Etc/GMT",datetime_format: "%b %e, %Y %l:%M:%S %p",item_description_style: "text+tn",item_thumbnail: "full",item_thumbnail_selection: "auto",article_num: "15",rssmikle_item_podcast: "off",keyword_inc: "",keyword_exc: ""};feedwind_show_widget_iframe(params);})();</script><div style="font-size:10px; text-align:center; width:350px;"><a href="http://feed.mikle.com/" target="_blank" style="color:#CCCCCC;">RSS Feed Widget</a><!--Please display the above link in your web page according to Terms of Service.--></div><!-- end feedwind code -->
```

Quick help needed please.

Comment: Have you look at `onClick`?  I

Comment: Please read [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the effort to learn how to format your question - especially if you'd like help "immediately".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the HTMLs `onClick` to call a javascript function. Also corrected the javascript and made it readable. Note I have removed the `document.write` and replace with the https link, if your site uses both http and https, you will need to revert back to the `document.write`

```html
<button onClick='onClickFunc();'> Run script
  </button>

<!-- start feedwind code -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://feed.mikle.com/js/rssmikle.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function onClickFunc() {
    var params = {
      rssmikle_url: "http://news.google.co.in/news?pz=1&cf=all&ned=in&hl=en&topic=n&output=rss",
      rssmikle_frame_width: "400",
      rssmikle_frame_height: "500",
      frame_height_by_article: "0",
      rssmikle_target: "_blank",
      rssmikle_font: "Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif",
      rssmikle_font_size: "12",
      rssmikle_border: "off",
      responsive: "off",
      rssmikle_css_url: "",
      text_align: "left",
      text_align2: "left",
      corner: "off",
      scrollbar: "on",
      autoscroll: "on_mc",
      scrolldirection: "up",
      scrollstep: "3",
      mcspeed: "30",
      sort: "New",
      rssmikle_title: "on",
      rssmikle_title_sentence: "Indian Latest News - As it happens",
      rssmikle_title_link: "",
      rssmikle_title_bgcolor: "#0066FF",
      rssmikle_title_color: "#FFFFFF",
      rssmikle_title_bgimage: "",
      rssmikle_item_bgcolor: "#FFFFFF",
      rssmikle_item_bgimage: "",
      rssmikle_item_title_length: "55",
      rssmikle_item_title_color: "#0066FF",
      rssmikle_item_border_bottom: "on",
      rssmikle_item_description: "on",
      item_link: "on",
      rssmikle_item_description_length: "150",
      rssmikle_item_description_color: "#666666",
      rssmikle_item_date: "gl1",
      rssmikle_timezone: "Etc/GMT",
      datetime_format: "%b %e, %Y %l:%M:%S %p",
      item_description_style: "text+tn",
      item_thumbnail: "full",
      item_thumbnail_selection: "auto",
      article_num: "15",
      rssmikle_item_podcast: "off",
      keyword_inc: "",
      keyword_exc: ""
    };
    feedwind_show_widget_iframe(params);
  }
  document.write(" <button onClick = 'onClickFunc();' > Run script < /button>");
</script>

<div style="font-size:10px; text-align:center; width:350px;">
  <a href="http://feed.mikle.com/" target="_blank" style="color:#CCCCCC;"> RSS Feed Widget</a>
  <!--Please display the above link in your web page according to Terms of Service.-->
</div>
<!-- end feedwind code -->
```

Comment: <button onClick='onClickFunc();'>Run script</button>

function onClickFunc() {
// Your script goes here
}

Comment: Is that what you are saying? When i put the js in "// Your script goes here", the page is displaying button,  "function onClickFunc() { "  text and below that the script is executing without even the click. Pls clarify..

Comment: If you don't have a seperate javascript file you will need to further wrap in <script>function onClickFunc() { // Your script goes here }</script>

Comment: Sorry it didn't give the desired result. :(

Comment: And you still haven't provided the desired edits to your question

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'm still unable to execute the script after the click of a button with the code give by you. May be i'm asking for 2 much but can i request you to please demonstrate it with my Jquery? I'm a newbie....

Comment: I've formatted it correctly. Can you help me now please?

Comment: Sorry the query isn't executing the script after clicking the button.

Comment: Hey that's perfect.. Thanks a ton. But button is disappearing after the execution of script... Can u suggest pls?

Comment: add `document.write("<button onClick='onClickFunc();'>Run script</button>");` after the function `feedwind_show_widget_iframe()`

Comment: No. Now it is showing 2 buttons. After clicking any of them, both buttons are disappearing, executing the script.

Comment: You haven't specified what you want the button to do after the first action.

Comment: When i try the earlier version of the code that worked well in my website, the page is reloading after clicking the button & only the feed is getting displayed instead of it only being a section of the page.

Comment: Hi Karwalski, will you be able to provide solution to this?